# Files cannot be merged because visual source safe doesn't support merging of files with different encoding

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I am working on a project which is on Visual Source Safe(VSS). Me and my colleague were working on the same file. I am working in Visual Studio 2010 with VSS 2005, while my colleague was working in VIsual studio 2013 with VSS 2006.

My colleague committed her changes with no errors, but when I tried to get latest version of the file I am getting this error:

> Cannot be merged because visual source safe doesn't support merging of
>   files with different encoding

The option that worked earlier for such an error is completely deleteing a file from local drive (of course keeping a backup copy!), and then recreating the file from visual studio & copy pasting the content from backup file.

But I am sure there will be some way out as the method I followed earlier doesn't seem to be the best practice.

Also, I cannot check in file; same error arises.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your file encoding in Visual Studio and the version in VSS database and see if they are the same.

To check the encoding in VSS, please locate the file in VSS, right click it -> Properties and check Type field.